# Nginx ingress class with two ingress controllers not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I want to have two ingresses in order to have a different load balancer for each (AWS ELB).

I follow the [official doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#using-ingressclasses) but I did not find an example.

So I created two ingress controllers, each with its class:

```
controller:
  service:
    ...
  ingressClassResource:
    name: api-ingress
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx"
```

the other one (not created te same way so it is json):

```
controller: {
  publishService: { enabled: true },
  // watchIngressWithoutClass: true,
  // ingressClassByName: true,
  ingressClassResource: {
    name: 'streaming-ingress',
    enabled: true,
    default: false,
    controllerValue: 'k8s.io/ingress-nginx',
  },
```

Then I create two ingresses with:

```
      metadata: {
        name: 'api-ingress',
      },
      spec: {
        ingressClassName: 'api-ingress',
        rules: [
          {...
```

and

```
      metadata: {
        name: 'smartproxy-ingress',
      },
      spec: {
        ingressClassName: 'streaming-ingress',
        defaultBackend: ...
      },
    },
```

The issue is that both ingresses use the same controller, `api-ingress`.

The ingress controllers are well created and target each a different LB as configured but they kind of mix together. There are events in the logs of each controller that correspond two both ingresses. I understand from that that the ingress classes are not working.

```
I0706 08:53:16.997641       8 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"api-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-5f9dc488ff-6tbt8", UID:"6dfdc93e-90ab-4abb-9b48-26b67521beef", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"22708", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0706 08:55:19.423635       8 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"api-ingress", UID:"2b6ea52a-2dee-4fa7-995f-452bc8fa96c4", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"23218", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0706 08:55:19.424410       8 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"smartproxy-ingress", UID:"74faf321-a9c4-45f8-994b-52bddd2c69a1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"23219", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

Here are the 2 ingresses using the same LB:

[image: Both ingresses use same LB]

Any idea? Did someone succeed with several nginx ingresses and controllers?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the docs (but google did not find it for me :-) ).

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/index.md#how-to-easily-install-multiple-instances-of-the-ingress-nginx-controller-in-the-same-cluster-

You need to set the right parameters and see how it is mapped in the helm chart (clone the github repo and do a search).

What I was missing was the electionId which need to be different for each controller. Also the controllerValue must be set to a specific value for each controller.